# How to test functions that take a BeautifulSoup object as a parameter via Mock or Pickle?

Tags: python, unit-testing, web-scraping, mocking, pytest

I have created a web scraper in Python (using Python 3.x) and I want to unit-test functions that take a Beautiful Soup object as a parameter. The best option seems to be to try to `mock` the Beautiful Soup object, but I have not yet been able to do so. I realize `mock` testing is sometimes frowned upon, however, I am trying to avoid re-factoring, and I need to apply similar tests to several other scenarios.

Separately, I've seen `pickle` referenced as an alternative to mock for testing file I/O (though I have not seen BS4 referenced in those examples). However, considering the security concerns, it may not be the best option here, as I do not control the data being requested.

The actual BeautifulSoup object is created with very simple code.

```
source = requests.get("https://www.footballguys.com/stats/game-logs-against/teams?team=ARI&year=2022")
     soup_object = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")
```

To illustrate, here is the most basic example of a function taking the BS4 object as a parameter:

```
def scrape_full_team_names(soup_object):
    full_team_names = []
    teams_location = soup_object.find_all("option", limit=32)
    for team in teams_location:
        for string in team.stripped_strings:
            full_team_names.append(string)
    return full_team_names
```

And the barebones example of a unit test for the basic list example:

```
def test_scrape_full_team_names(...):
    ...
    assert scrape_full_team_names(...) == [
        "Arizona Cardinals",
        "Atlanta Falcons",
        "Baltimore Ravens",
        "Buffalo Bills",
        "Carolina Panthers",
        "Chicago Bears",
        ...
    ]
```

Certainly, since I am simply checking the contents of a list, I could obviously break out this function and test the list separately, but this is just one example, and I need to do the same thing for other more complicated functions.

I have tried to adapt other tests I have created using pytest-mock and monkeypatch, but have not been successful doing it for BS4. The process is also seemingly not as simple as the GET example referenced in the monkeypatch docs: [Pytest Monkeypatching Docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html#monkeypatching-mocking-modules-and-environments)

```
def test_valid_year(mocker):
    mocker.patch("builtins.input", side_effect =["cat", "1999", "2022"])
    result = valid_year()
    assert result == 2022

def test_fantasy_point_thresholds_default(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("builtins.input", lambda _:"")
    result = fantasy_point_thresholds()
    assert result == (20, 15, 12, 12)
```

Any thoughts, or anyone willing to help nudge me in the right direction, would be greatly appreciated!